# Automating wifi login with applescript

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I have a wifi network that loads a webview on connecting that has fields for username and password and a login button. is there a way to automate the login process when that network is connected?

Comment: Is your problem how to know when connected to that network, or how to automate the login? What code do you have for either aspect of the problem so far?

Comment: Does your system run `/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app` and you want to respond to that?

Comment: This may help https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140843